# React js - Issue Implementing router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement react router, the code is working fine for only index path i.e *"/"*, but giving 404 error for rest url's. Here is my code below :

```
***** HTML ***** 

<div id="rootDiv"></div>

<script src="/assets/libs/reactjs/react.development.js" crossorigin></script> 
<script src="/assets/libs/reactjs/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/reactjs/browser.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/reactjs/react-router.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/reactjs/react-router-dom.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="/components.js"></script>


***** components.js *****

var { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } = ReactRouterDOM;

class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>Dashboard</div>
        )
    }
}

class LoginBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>LoginBox</div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={LoginBox}/>
            <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('rootDiv')
);
```

Here above LoginBox is showing up, but gives 404 error when I hit /dashboard in URL. I got many answers from google and stack-overflow, followed all the required changes/steps but I"m not able to fix the issue.

Please do let me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Your js codes seems like es6 but I think your babel configuration missing. If you don't want to struggle babel configuration now you can try to convert your codes es5

Comment: switch is used to render only one path that matches first. you should remove switch here.

Comment: @Rizvan ya took out switch but not working

Comment: @B77 Please check if dashboard.js file is being imported properly in page. I think there something wrong with path of the file or the component is not exported from the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need the "exact" in the dashboard route. Try changing it to:

```
<Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
```